# issue with singular and plural

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am finding the missing word from first string when compare two strings

run time I enter sentence:

- first sentence  :  This is my testing for matching algoritham
- second sentence :  This is my testing for matchings algoritham for application by website

now I remove the run time **my** keyword in the second sentence and now look like(This is testing for matchings algoritham for application by website) and **then press the show removable button**

**current output**:

Missing Word Finds: for matching algoritham

**I want to**:

my

.aspx:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="ftextbox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px" Height="200px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="stextbox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px" Height="200px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Show Removable Text" OnClick="Button2_Click"/><br />
```

.aspx.cs

```
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            string tests;

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Label4.Text = "";
            }
            var string1 = ftextbox.Text.Split(' ');
            var string2 = stextbox.Text.Split(' ');

            //var result = string1.Except(string2);                 // means if want which is in first not in 2nd 

            foreach (var word in string1)
            {
                if (word == string2[i] || word + "ing" == string2[i] || word + "es" == string2[i] || word + "ies" == string2[i] || word.Replace("oo", "ee") == string2[i])
                {
                    string1[i] = "";
                    i++;
                }
            }

            tests = String.Join(" ", string1);

            Label4.Text += "Missing Word Finds: " + string.Join(" ", tests) + "<br/><br/>";

        }
```

[Image of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKC85.png)

https://www.ef.com/in/english-resources/english-grammar/singular-and-plural-nouns/         - singular-and-plural link

please help

Comment: By "finding the missing word" you meant that you need to find the words that are on second string but not on first string, right? Why are you verifying those "ing", "es", etc ?

Comment: see I clear your doubt ```first sentence  :  This is my testing for matching algoritham``` and ```second sentence :  This is my testing for matchings algoritham for application by website          (now I remove the my keyword from the second string)``` and ```now I want to only :my```

Comment: @LeoRossetti I remove the my keyword from the second string which is available in first string I want to get that word(my)

Comment: You want to return the first word missing when comparing two strings, right? In your example you removed the word "my" so when comparing both strings you want a program that return that first missing word. Is that right?

Comment: I can give you an example of a program that compare 2 strings and return a list of all missing words when comparing string1 to string2. Will that helps you?

Comment: I can give you an example of a program that compare 2 strings and return a list of all missing words when comparing string1 to string2. - ok can you show your example

Comment: ok, I'll help you if you need more than that. No problem.

Comment: @LeoRossetti I hope you understood what I am trying to say

Comment: In first sentence ```matching``` keyword and second sentence ```matchings``` so I don't want this type of word

Comment: I see now. Just a second.

Comment: I adited it a bit. Is this in the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know by any doubts or if I misunderstood it:

I made it on C# Console, you just need to adapt some simple variables.

```cs
            string textBox1 = "This is my testing for matching algoritham";
            string textBox2 = "This is testing for matchings algoritham for application by website";

            var string1 = textBox1.Split(' ');
            var string2 = textBox2.Split(' ');

            List<string> string2List = textBox2.Split(' ').ToList();

            string tests;

            List<string> missingWords = new List<string>();

            foreach (var word in string1)
            {
                if (!string2List.Contains(word) && !word.EndsWith("ing") && !word.EndsWith("es") && !word.EndsWith("ies"))
                {
                    missingWords.Add(word);
                }

                //if (word == string2[i] || word + "ing" == string2[i] || word + "es" == string2[i] || word + "ies" == string2[i] || word.Replace("oo", "ee") == string2[i])
                //{
                //    string1[i] = "";
                //    i++;
                //}
            }

            tests = String.Join(" ", missingWords);

            Console.Write("Missing Word Finds: " + string.Join(" ", tests));
```

Comment: work fine but when I remove two word from the second string then not work because of the ```break;``` that is the reason

Comment: I am trying to last two days please help

Comment: see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/rypvL.png I removed the two words from the second string (my,for) but it only display my because two time for available in second string

Comment: Yes, the code will only return words that are missing, and because we have multiple references to the word 'for' as you know, if you remove only one reference, we still have the other one. So it will not be listed.

Comment: have you any solution for that?

Comment: any solution for  multiple references word ```for```